# Travelling to Europe from India and then to UAE

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, uae

I'm planning for my travel around mid next year to Europe from India. I'll be travelling to Netherlands, Norway and Germany. With that, I'm also planning to extend my trip and visit UAE.

I'll be applying for both Schengen and UAE visa, but before I do that, wanted to know if I can travel from Europe to UAE?

From the eligibility criteria mentioned on the UAE website, it is said that I need to show onward and return confirmed ticket. The origin and destination countries can be anything, right? Or, are there any restrictions that it has to be 'from' India?

Also, any pro tips to keep in mind when travelling to multiple countries with multiple visas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can travel from Europe to the UAE without issue (in fact, I'm doing exactly that tomorrow).

"Onward" tickets are required by many countries.  Basically it just means that you need a ticket out of their country, as some level of proof that you will be leaving when your stay there is complete.  That ticket could be back to your home country (ie, India), or some other third country - as long as you have a ticket and generally have the required paperwork (eg, visas) to visit that country then you'll be fine.